# AspNet core 401 - No SecurityTokenValidator when adding the token

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, bearer-token, jwt

For a Jwt token:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg
var token = responseMsg.Content?
           .ReadAsStringAsync()
           .GetAwaiter()
           .GetResult();
```

Used to authorize a post request, like this:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://...");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```

I'm getting this error:

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No
>   SecurityTokenValidator available for token: "eyJ..."

After a closer look to the request in postman I discovered that the issue are the "" added to the token on the header:

[image: Postman]

That is why I add the token like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.Replace("\"", "")}");
```

And this **works**, but it seems "dirty" to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: could you share more about the creation of the token, it seems that you are retrieving it out of the scope of the code shared

Comment: @Juanito info added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deserialize the response object so that you can use it as a string:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg
var response = responseMsg.Content?
           .ReadAsStringAsync()
           .GetAwaiter()
           .GetResult();
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
return token;
```

Now the string is ready to be included in the header as a bearer token.